# SQLalchemy updating all rows instead of one

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This code is supposed to update a post in the database that matches 'post_id'. But it updates every post in the table.

***The code has been edited so it works correctly.***

```
@app.route('/update/<post_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update(post_id):
  if 'username' not in session:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
  post = Post.query.get(post_id)  
  form = PostForm(obj=post)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
      return render_template('update.html', form=form)
    else:
      Post.query.filter(Post.post_id==int(post_id)).update(dict(
        title=form.title.data, body=form.body.data))
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('retrieve'))

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('update.html', form=form, post_id=post_id)


class Post(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'posts'
  post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  author = db.Column(db.String(128))
  title = db.Column(db.String(128))
  body = db.Column(db.Text)

  def __init__(self, author, title, body):
    self.author = author
    self.title = title
    self.body = body

<form method="POST" action="/update/{{post_id}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for equality of passed `post_id` with the `Post` class attribute `post_id`.

```
Post.query.filter(Post.post_id==int(post_id)).update(dict(
        title=form.title.data, body=form.body.data))
```

Your query should return all the `Post` records because you checked `post_id` with the `post_id` itself (not with the `Post` class attribute).

Comment: I made the changes and it did not work. The query returns 0 and updates nothing.

Comment: change the type of `post_id` to int because you have defined `post_id` as integer . check my update.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<post_id>'"

Comment: could you print the post_id? What it shows? Pls check for post id integer or not at very first.

Comment: With print(post_id) it prints "<post_id>"

Comment: How you get post_id in the frontend?

Comment: Do you think it might have to do with my HTTP post action in retrieve.html? See my edit above.

Comment: it should be `<form method="POST" action="/update/{{post_id}}">` . Hope you get post_id from backend.

Comment: Now I get a 404. That is all the code I have. Not sure what you mean by backend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138700/discussion-between-avinash-raj-and-wildexploit).